# preserve=timestamps is not permitted

Tags: command-line, cp

I use `--preserve=timestamps` when I copy a file.
This worked under Ubuntu 20.04, but running 22.04 I get:

> cp: preserving times for '/d/news/2024-01-04.COA DEMS - Mazars Report.pdf': Operation not permitted

The result is that every copied file is the newest version.

Comment: What is the source and destination filesystem?

Comment: if it works with `sudo` you don't own the file it is copied to or the destination. "cp" is not allowed to bypass Linux security :)